# Cooked bacon too salty

Tags: salt

I Have already cooked in the slow cooker overnight the bacon and forgot to soak.  It is now really really salty and unfit to eat.  How can I solve now and get rid of the salt.

Thanks

Bernie

Answer (score 1):

I'd cut it up into small pieces, wash it in cold water (partly to cool it, though this will get rid of some salt), dry it and freeze it in small portions. Then the bacon can be added to dishes which might get some salt anyway, such as pasta sauces and casseroles (chicken chasseur).

It should be labelled so you know to use less salt when cooking, or less stock, or a lower-salt stock (which is my default anyway).

If you it want to use it immediately I suggest slicing it (assuming you're starting with a bacon joint from the fact you're slow cooking it) and then boiling it in water for a few minutes.

Answer (score -1):

You can put your bacon in a bowl and pour some boiled water until covering all bacon.
Stir it up and leave it for 2 minutes.

Repeat this again but leaving the bacon for a minute.
After that let it dry and cook it again.

It should remove excess salt.

source: http://www.kitchenbutterfly.com/how-to/de-salt-bacon/

Answer (score -1):

Today was the first time I cooked bacon and didn't drain the grease off fully and it was super salty... may help to drain the grease well by putting in on paper towels..

Comment: I think the question is really asking: "My bacon is already cooked and too salty, how can I tone down the salt?".  We would have to assume that the grease was already drained and the bacon is now ready to serve.  Do you have any suggestions for that?